# Why @PreDestory not working on websocket @ServerEndpoint?

Tags: java, websocket, cdi

I log some message to see the lifecycle of `@ServerEndpoint`. `PostConstruct`, `onOpen`, `onClose` are triggered in turns, but `@PreDestroy` is never triggered. Do I miss something?

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
@ServerEndpoint("/")
public class ServerWebSocket {
    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("PostConstruct");
    }
    @OnOpen
    public void open(Session session) {
        System.out.println("OnOpen");

    }
    @OnClose
    public void close(Session session) {
        System.out.println("OnClose");
    }
    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("PreDestroy");
    }
}
```

I use GlassFish4 with bean.xml in WEB-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

Comment: When are you expecting this to be destroyed? You don't have a scope.

Comment: What server are you using/ JEE version? As far as i can read in the specs, PreDestroy should be executed in this example.

Comment: @BalusC: thanks for your help, GlassFish 4 with Tyrus. A `java.sql.Connection` produced by CDI (use `@Produces`) was injected to this endpoint, but connection never close by `@Disposes`. I think it might be related to the malfunction of `@PreDestory`.

Answer (score 0):

`@OnOpen` and `@OnClose` callbacks are triggered by the lifecycle of every WebSocket session.

There is no any CDI scope specified, which could be used with WebSocket endpoints. And this is ok, because it has it's own session.

So, why is `@PostConstruct` triggered? WebSocket specification says, that:

> Websocket endpoints running in the Java EE platform **must** have full dependency injection support as described in the CDI specification.

And `@PostConstruct` API Doc points:

> The PostConstruct annotation is used on a method that needs to be executed after dependency injection is done to perform any initialization. ... This annotation **MUST** be supported on all classes that support dependency injection.

Why `@PreDestroy` then doesn't work? I think, Websocket endpoints behave like singletons, and `@PreDestroy` will be triggered during removing of the instance, which will occur just before application stop. You could check it in your environment by stopping application from the GlassFish administration console.

Comment: I've shut down GlassFish and didn't see `@PreDestroy`. I checked websocekt [spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/websocket-1_1-mrel-spec/websocket-1.1-maintenance-release-final.pdf), and it says `Each instance of the Endpoint class in this typical case only handles connections to the endpoint from one and only one peer`. Is it still a singleton, or just my misunderstanding of that?